# redirecting urls that contain the "?" character in the file names

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I'm a novice php/mysql developer and need some help.

I was working on a project with a .NET developer. He built a URL redirecting function in .NET that uses the `?` in the  URL (eg, `mysite.com?123` redirects to `www.realsite.com`. This developer has now disappeared on me and I no longer have access to the server.

I need to move my domain to a new server and recreate this functionality in php/mySQL.  I have about 40 urls that I need to support using this technique (they're embedded in QR codes).  I don't need a solution that generates new redirects this way - I've got a different solution going forward.

My new server will be on bluehost.

Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replicate the original setup you dond't need to involve PHP at all. You can accomplish this at the server level using some `RewriteRules`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^123$
RewriteRule ^$ http://realsite.com/
```

See also http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: That worked! I was trying to use 'redirect' rather than your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The query string can be found in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 0):

On your old host for `mysite.com` domain create a .htaccess file in DOCUMENT_ROOT like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for HTTP traffic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.realsite.com/? [R=301,L]

# for HTTPS traffic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.realsite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Above code will redirect every URI that looks like `mysite.com?foo` to `http://www.realsite.com/` with HTTP status code 301.

`?` in the end will discard any existing QUERY string.

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. Is there any way I can get rid of the ?foo on the redirected URL?

Answer (score -1):

```
http://example.com?123
```

would be the equivalent of doing

```
http://example.com/index.php?123
```

Your choices would be either to catch those codes via mod_rewrite and redirect the request to a script specifically set up to handle these legacy urls. Or you can modify the index.php script to look for the codes and do whatever it has to at that point.